How to Catch Error and Resume API Call (Smartsheet API Python SDK)
I am trying to write an API call using list_sheets and get_sheet to first, gather a list of all sheets, and second, add the additional sheet data for each sheet ID (Sheet Owner, Workspace Name, and Workspace ID). I am able to successfully start gathering this data with my current code below. The problem I am running into is that every time I run the code, at different places in the list, I will get an error response saying "Error retrieving sheets: 'content-type'" Now, I would like to be able to get through all 10,000+ sheets without an error terminating the loop so I can process as many of these sheets and their data as possible.
    try:
        # Get a list of all sheets
        response = smart.Sheets.list_sheets(include_all=True)
    
        # Extract sheet information
        sheets_list = response.data
    
        # Create a dictionary to store sheet and workspace data
        sheet_data = {
            'Sheet Name': [], 
            'Sheet ID': [],
            'Sheet Link': [],
            'Sheet Owner': [],
            'Workspace Name': [],
            'Workspace ID': []
        }
        
        # Populate the dictionary
        for sheet in sheets_list:
            sheet_data['Sheet ID'].append(sheet.id)
            sheet_data['Sheet Name'].append(sheet.name)
            sheet_data['Sheet Link'].append(sheet.permalink)
            
            # Using get_sheet call, cycle though sheet ids to get owner and workspace data
            sheet2 = smart.Sheets.get_sheet(sheet.id, column_ids='0', row_ids='0')
            try:
                sheet_data['Sheet Owner'].append(sheet2.owner)
                sheet_data['Workspace Name'].append(sheet2.workspace.name)
                sheet_data['Workspace ID'].append(sheet2.workspace.id)
                print(sheet2.workspace.name)
                            
            except:
                sheet_data['Sheet Owner'].append('None')
                sheet_data['Workspace Name'].append('None')
                sheet_data['Workspace ID'].append('None')
                print(f"Sheet {sheet.id} not in workspace")
                    
        # Create a DataFrame from the dictionary
        df_sheets = pd.DataFrame(sheet_data)
        print(len(df_sheets))
        print("sheet_data table populated")
    
    
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error retrieving sheets: {e}")

I have tried moving the outside try and except inside the loop to see if it would potentially continue to evaluate the next sheets despite an Error being raised.
    for sheet in sheets_list:
        try:
            sheet_data['Sheet ID'].append(sheet.id)
            sheet_data['Sheet Name'].append(sheet.name)
            sheet_data['Sheet Link'].append(sheet.permalink)
            
            # Using get_sheet call, cycle though sheet ids to get workspace data
            sheet2 = smart.Sheets.get_sheet(sheet.id, column_ids='0', row_ids='0')
            try:
                sheet_data['Sheet Owner'].append(sheet2.owner)
                sheet_data['Workspace Name'].append(sheet2.workspace.name)
                sheet_data['Workspace ID'].append(sheet2.workspace.id)
                print(sheet2.workspace.name)
                            
            except:
                sheet_data['Sheet Owner'].append('None')
                #sheet_data['Sheet Version'].append(sheet2.version)
                sheet_data['Workspace Name'].append('None')
                sheet_data['Workspace ID'].append('None')
                print(f"Sheet {sheet.id} not in workspace")
                
        except ValueError as e:
                print(f"Error retrieving sheet {sheet.id}: {e}")

I also tried adding 'continue' at the end of the second except to try and for it to continue processing sheets but I still received the same error and it terminated prematurely.
